# radio button not pre-selecting on screen loading

Tags: xamarin.forms, radio-button

I feel this is weird. i can't get the Radio button to pre-select a saved value and it's driving me mad. I have this xaml:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Parities"
                 RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding Parity}">
        <RadioButton Value="1" Content="Income" />
        <RadioButton Value="-1" Content="Expense" />
        <RadioButton Value="0" Content="Neutral" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Furthermore, even if I replace SelectedValue with a hard coded literal value "1" (for Income), the radio button still show up blank. The only way that works is by setting IsChecked on each of the 3 options to have the them pre-selected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code ,I created a simple demo, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. It just works properly.

You can refer to the following code:

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <radiobuttondemos:MyViewModel></radiobuttondemos:MyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"
             RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding Parity}">
        <RadioButton Value="1" Content="Income" />
        <RadioButton Value="-1" Content="Expense" />
        <RadioButton Value="0" Content="Neutral" />
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

The `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string groupName;

    object parity;
    public object Parity
    {
        get => parity;
        set
        {
            parity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Parity));
        }
    }


    public MyViewModel () {

        GroupName = "Parities";

        Parity = "1";
    }

    public string GroupName
    {
        get => groupName;
        set
        {
            groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupName));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Note:**

In the constructor of `MyViewModel`, I initialize the value of  variable `Parity`  as follows:

```
  Parity = "1";
```

And if we initialize  a value as follows, the UI will not pre-select the saved value :

```
 Parity = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @Haoest，may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Yes I've been attempting this sporadically past few days. I got your sample to work and I narrowed down the cause of my issue. The data type of my Parity property is int, where yours is object. When I change my type to string, it works fine too. Somehow int does not work. I even created a simple IValueConverter to convert from int to string. It still does not work... Something is very odd. Can you offer more expertise please?

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said, and I have created a new issue, you can follow it up here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15239 .